# Condensed some code, wondering if I may have added any unintended vulnerabilities or problems:

Tags: javascript, web

I started with this code as part of a for loop:

```
        var depthCat = "DMAD" + i.toString();
        var tempDepth = document.getElementById("DMAD" + i.toString());
        var depth = document.getElementById("DMAD" + i.toString()).value;
```

started thinking it was a little too verbose and slimmed it down to this:

```
        var depth = document.getElementById("DMAD" + i.toString()).value;
```

my understanding of preventing injections and the like is limited, so I'm wondering if I've created any potential issues for myself?

Comment: No, you have not introduced any new vulnerabilities as your concise code is functionally identical

Comment: i.toString() is superfluous if its from a loop. Though if it is from/in a loop using getElementById is not the most performant way, why not use querySelectorAll() and loop over the elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be careful, if no HTML element is found, then you will get an error

You should test if `document.getElementById("DMAD" + i)` is not `null`, or execute

```
var dmadElement = document.getElementById("DMAD" + i)
var depth = dmadElement ? dmadElement.value : null
```

or

```
var depth = null
try {
    depth = document.getElementById("DMAD" + i).value
catch (e) {
    // console.error(e)
}
```